# Woocommerce show featured product with category name with some description?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am using [woocommerce shortcode](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) `[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]` to show featured product. It is showing all the featured product. But with this I also want to show the product category name with little bit description under the product `(description must be 10-20 words with readmore link)`. I have gone through the documentation but I have not got any result like as I want. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 simple steps:

1) Open your `content-product.php` from `themes/YourTheme/woocommerce/` folder  ( If you can't find this file, then copy it from `plugins/woocommerce/templates` folder)

2) For displaying **product categories**.

```
    $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
    echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
```

3) For displaying **product short description**, Make sure your product have short description in WP **Backend**

```
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
```

Comment: @phpdevelopr  this one is working fine to show category with description but this one is blocking my checkout page. The checkout page showing process but not doing any checkout. After remove this lines it is doing checkout. Another thing this one is also hiding my cart totals in sidebar widget..

Comment: @NewUser Hmm..Then i think, Can we discussed in Chat group. I already created it -  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32560/woocommerce

Comment: can you tell me how to link the featured products to the category not to the product details page?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would probably need to add a filter through Wordpress for this.

If you're good with PHP, you wouldn't have an issue. Read more about this here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters and here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter